# Having trouble solving matrix equation with two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have an equation: $VAV^T=B$

Where `A` and `B` are unknown 3x3 matrices. `V` is fully defined 3x3 matrix representing points in 3D:
$$\begin{matrix}
x1 & x2 & x3 \\
y1 & y2 & y3 \\
z1 & z2 & z3
\end{matrix}$$

To make it simpler, we can assume all z values equal 1.

How can I reframe this problem so that `A` and `B` can be represented?

`A` is a symmetric matrix of the form:
$$\begin{matrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c
\end{matrix}$$

`B` is also symmetric of the form:
$$\begin{matrix}
i^2 + x^2 & xy & x \\
xy & i^2 + y^2 & y \\
x & y & 1
\end{matrix}$$

Is there a way to solve for the 6 unknowns (a, b, c, i, x, y) - short of breaking this into a system of polynomial equations?

Comment: Is $V$ a matrix or a vector? Either way, does the fact that $A$'s inverse is achieved by replacing each element of the diagonal by its reciprocal help? Your question could use some more clarity.

Comment: I don't see what's to stop you from letting $A$ be anything you want, and then defining $B$ by $B=VAV^t$.

Comment: I have added more information to the question. It was definitely underexplained in its first iteration. Essentially, the system will be defined by a set of three known points (x1, y1, 1), (x2, y2, 1), (x3, y3, 1). There are 6 unknowns (a, b, c, i, x, y). I’m looking for a way to solve for these unknowns.

Comment: Do you want to have all solutions, or just a method to get one ? is your $V$ supposed to be invertible ?  orthogonal? could you add more context ? (it seems to come from a 3D problem)

Comment: I suppose that fully defined means "invertible" ?